# Limit number of selections on material-table 1.36.2?

Tags: material-table

I'm attempting to limit the number of rows that can be selected to any set integer (1 for example) on an older version of Material-Table (1.36.2) as I'm not able to upgrade the project to Material-UI 4.0 or above at this time (Still on 3.9.2).

I saw [this response](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/869) but was unable to apply it properly on my end.

I'd like to be able to disable all selection checkboxes as shown in the answer to #869 once a certain number of selections has been met without upgrading material-table or material-ui if possible, upgrading at this time would cause breaking changes to my project.

Comment: Can you show us your code within a codepen?

Comment: I'm using the same format as the shown within the Basic Selection example [here](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/selection)

Comment: Can you show us the error you are getting? Because it works for me.